# ImageIO - get image type and exif data

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Given some source file (or more generic - input stream), I need to find out

- is it an image
- if it is an image, then retrieve its type (png/jpeg/gif/etc)
- retrieve exif data, if available

I looked at the API, but it is not clear how to get the type of image or Exif data.

Comment: To get the type, just look at the file extension.

Comment: The file extension is never a guarantee of the file type. Nothing can stop anyone from illegally renaming the file.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Last time I had to do this, a couple of years ago, the standard API couldn't read EXIF data. This library can do so though:

http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

Comment: It seems that this product is the metadata-extractor proposed by matt burns below

Answer (score 17):

Easy answer:
Use https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/

If you're crazy/brave/curious, you could get image type from the stream by reading the first few bytes (these are [magic numbers](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html)). I believe the exif is generally at the start of the stream too.

Comment: Magic number link → Error 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Here the `magic number` link from the internet archive https://web.archive.org/web/20170611142413/https://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html

Answer (score 8):

It's an old thread, but I was doing this recently and found the Apache Tika library useful.
Particularly for analysing generic streams to detect what content is in them.

Thought it might help others.

http://tika.apache.org/

Comment: Note that Tika uses metadata-extractor under the hood :).