# How can I extract an image's keywords using ImageIO

Tags: java, image, metadata, keyword, javax.imageio

I have tagged a few keywords to an image in Photoshop and I'm attempting to read these keywords using Java. But right now I'm only able to read the image's format with the help of other questions that has been asked here. I have gone through the ImageIO class documentation and I could not find any functions that extract keywords out from image. Is there any other way to extract out keywords and other information such as data and time created?

Comment: I think you are looking for `Exif` data which is a different library

Comment: This answer looks like it would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310162/imageio-get-image-type-and-exif-data

Comment: The [standard metadata format of ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/standard_metadata.html) should give you the very basics.. But, if extracting metadata is all you want to do, you will find that drewnoakes or metadata-extractor (as linked in @JasonSperske's answer) has better support and is more natural to work with.