# Where can I find the list of metadata type to extract specific exif

Tags: java, metadata-extractor

I'm working on a project where I need to make pdf from image and merge it. For this I use PDFBox but at some point I need to read the exif of an image like the orientation and the resolution and so I go with metadata-extractor. I didn't find any useful doc or example.

I find that I can read a specifics exif but I don't know how exactly

Comment: EXIF is a public standard, google it.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll go check that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageIO - get image type and exif data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310162/imageio-get-image-type-and-exif-data) . And if you want to rotate based on the orientation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905868/how-to-rotate-jpeg-images-based-on-the-orientation-metadata  (just used these 3 days ago at work!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list : [List](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/wiki/SampleOutput), they list most of the tag you need ( a more complete one : [here](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html)